# Can dotenv be used with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Dumb question, I know,  but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer. The library was recommended for an AngularJS app but the examples I've found are all for Angular. Thanks.

Comment: It's not meant for either; it's completely independent of both. Assuming you mean https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - thank you, I've rephrased the question. Understand that it is stand alone.  I haven't found any examples of it being used in an AngularJS app, I have seen examples of it being used in Angular. That's why I was wondering if there was some reason it can't be used with AngularJS or isn't recommended to be used with AngularJS

Comment: There's a much easier way of determining whether in can be used -- try it. Whether it's recommended or not is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it is opinion-based.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  - thank you. Looking for a tutorial or example to follow in order to try it. I have yet to find one which is why my question came up.